# Extracting child elements from XML documents w

Tags: xml, python-3.x, parsing, lxml

I have an XML file from which I need to extract values. However, the text to be extracted (after the ImageData tag but still in the Figure tag) does not appear to have tags for each element. Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Created from PDF via Acrobat SaveAsXML -->
<!-- Mapping Table version: 28-February-2003 -->
<TaggedPDF-doc>
<?xpacket begin='﻿' id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c015 84.159810, 2016/09/10-02:41:30        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
            xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
         <dc:format>xml</dc:format>
         <dc:creator>
            <rdf:Seq>
               <rdf:li>BERKSDB</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Seq>
         </dc:creator>
         <dc:title>
            <rdf:Alt>
               <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">IBM Daeja ViewONE Professional document (114 pages)</rdf:li>
            </rdf:Alt>
         </dc:title>
         <xmp:CreateDate>2019-08-14T18:14:21-04:00</xmp:CreateDate>
         <xmp:CreatorTool>PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2</xmp:CreatorTool>
         <xmp:ModifyDate>2019-08-15T10:21:40-04:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
         <xmp:MetadataDate>2019-08-15T10:21:40-04:00</xmp:MetadataDate>
         <pdf:Producer>Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017 17 Paper Capture Plug-in</pdf:Producer>
         <xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:c48c4a75-6302-4ee7-8f75-6439db19faa9</xmpMM:DocumentID>
         <xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:5899f933-ff16-48ab-ae56-3fcce31bb82c</xmpMM:InstanceID>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>





















<?xpacket end="w"?>
<?xpacket end='r'?><Figure>

<ImageData src="images/Z4114390 ESLOG_img_0.jpg"/>
 &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt; &lt;iGoFieldAuditLog&gt; &lt;created&gt;2018-12-21 180033.387&lt;/created&gt;&lt;GAID&gt;6641 &lt;/GAID&gt;&lt;clickWrapLog/&gt;&lt;eApp&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22.707'' ObjectValue=&quot;United States&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S' '/&gt;&lt;Clientl D&gt;46ec1154-36ca-43ad-90f8-cd6c3d1 0c3cf&lt;/Clientl D&gt;&lt; Data UpdatedDateTi me= &quot;2018-12-20 20: 39 :43. 127&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;000TD&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_AgencyCode&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20 :39:43.127&quot; ObjectVal ue=&quot;000TD&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; Lagoni D=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; Fi rstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=' 'ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_AgencyCode_fmt&quot;/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me= &quot;2018-12-21 22: 59 :59. 34&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;true&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_AgencyCode_lck&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectValue=&quot;stephen_abrams@glic.com'' UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_Email&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectValue=''{&amp;quot;status&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;valid&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;message&amp;quot;:null}&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_Email_emdata&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22.707'' ObjectVal ue=''ste phe n_abrams@glic.com'' UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_Email_fmt&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 22:59:59.34&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;true&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_ Email_lck&quot;/&gt;&lt; Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39 :43.127&quot; ObjectVal ue=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; Logan ID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_FirstName&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me= &quot;2018-12-20 20: 39 :43. 14&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_FirstName_fmt''/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me=&quot;2018-12-20 20 :39 :43.14&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;STEPHEN ABRAMS&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_FullName&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39:49.673&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;STEPHEN ABRAMS&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_FullName_fmt&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 22:59:59.34&quot; ObjectValue='true&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_FullName_lck&quot;/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39:43.14&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S'' ObjectName=' 'AGENT_LastName' '/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20: 39:43.14'' ObjectVal ue=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; Logan ID=&quot;4xsdaGR D6641&quot; Fi rstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=' 'ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_LastName_fmt&quot;/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me= &quot;2018-12-20 20: 39 :43. 127&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;SA&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_Namelnitials&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectVal ue= &quot;2931&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; Lagoni D=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641 &quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_PIN&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectValue=&quot;2931&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=''ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_PIN_fmt&quot;/&gt;&lt; Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 22:59:59.34&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;true&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_PIN_lck&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectValue=&quot;0004X988&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; Fi rstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=' 'ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_WritingCode&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22. 707'' ObjectValue=&quot;0004X988&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=' 'STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S'' ObjectName=' 'AGENT_Writi ngCode_fmt&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me=' '2018-12-21 22 :59:59. 34'' ObjectVal ue='true&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_WritingCode_lck''/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22.707'' ObjectVal ue=''[{&amp;quot; name&amp;quot; :&amp;quot;0004X988&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;value&amp;quot; :&amp;quot;0004X988&amp;quot;, &amp;quot ;option1&amp;quot; :&amp;quot </Figure>
<Figure>

<ImageData src="images/Z4114390 ESLOG_img_1.jpg"/>
 UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AGENT_WritingCodel loptions&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39:34.0&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;12/20/2018&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ApplicationCreationDate&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 22:59:59. 34&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;X&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AppLocked&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:42. 72&quot; ObjectVal ue=''Yes&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ApplySigStatusSent&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40. 52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;M ansfield&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_CITY_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=''12/21/2018'' UpdatedBy=''1b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_D_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;21&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_DD_Pl&quot;/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02 :40. 52&quot; ObjectVal ue=' ~ pushee44@gmail.com'' UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_EMAIL_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;73.60. 74.35, 65.158.47.173, 10.101.27.12, 10.101.27.24&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_IP_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;December&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_M M_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;MA&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_STATE_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;9:02:40 PM&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_T_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;eSigned by Jessica L Armando&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_X_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;2018&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_YY_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:40.52&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;12/21/2018 9:02:40 PM&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;AUTH_SIG_Z_Pl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=''2018-12-21 21:02:45.91&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;Yes&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;CallM illiman_PrefixError&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:45.91&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. at System.RuntimeMethodHandle. lnvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection. RuntimeConstructorlnfo. lnvoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, Culturelnfo culture) at System.RuntimeType.Createlnstancelmpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, Culturelnfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark&amp;amp; stackMark) at System.Activator.Createlnstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, Culturelnfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at System.Activator.Createlnstance(Type type, Object[] args) at iPipelineExternalServicesProxy.ExternalServiceProxy.CreateFactory(String serviceName, Dictionary'2 parameters) in E:\Jenki ns\workspace\iGO\Base BuiId (iGO)\Base\CossCommonAssemblies\iPipelineExternalServicesProxy\iPipelineExternalServicesProxy\ExternalServiceProxy.cs:lir 40 at iPipelineExternalServicesProxy.ExternalServiceProxy.CallExternalService(string serviceName, Dictionary'2 dictionary) in E:\Jenkins\workspace\iGO\Base Build (iGO)\Base\CossCommonAssemblies\iPipelineExternalServicesProxy\iPipelineExternalServicesProxy\ExternalServiceProxy.cs:lir 27 at iPipelineCallMillimanCA.iPipelineCallMillimanCA.CallMillimanService(XmlDocument clientData, Cache cache, String prefix) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot.9.1.4\Base9.1.4\CossCustomAssemblies\iPipeline\iPipelineCallMillimanCA\iPipelineCall MillimanCA.cs:line </Figure>
<Figure>

<ImageData src="images/Z4114390 ESLOG_img_2.jpg"/>
 111&quot; UpdatedBy= &quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Call Milliman_PrefixErrorM sg&quot;/&gt; &lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :02:45.91&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;0&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Call Milliman_PrefixErrorType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20 :39:34. 0&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;260&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' Logan ID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Carrier&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39:43.11&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;Guardian Life Insurance Company&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Carrier_itmtxt&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me= &quot;2018-12-20 20: 39 :34. 0&quot; ObjectVal ue=&quot;260&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Carrier_itmval&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:22.69&quot; ObjectValue=''{&amp;quot;PIFirstName&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;Jessica&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;PILastName&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;Armando&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;CaseDescr UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;Case InformationFields&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 23 :00:27.26&quot; ObjectValue=''Complete'' UpdatedBy=''CWAdmin'' ObjectName=&quot;CaseStatus&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=''2018-12-21 23:00 :03. 23&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;Locked&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; LogonlD=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;CaseStatus_fmt&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 23:00:27.277&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;Jessica L ArmandoAPIAe-Submitted -Confirm. SentlSTEPHEN ABRAMSAAgentAe-Submitted -Confirm. Sent&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;CWAdmin&quot; ObjectName=&quot;CaseStatusHover&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTi me=&quot;2018-12-20 20 :39:34. 0&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;6641&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ClientlD&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:26.503&quot; ObjectVal ue=' 'https://consumergateway. ipipeIi ne. com/?token=5c130ae1 e889adc20891 a57fb043968359a6565cefa21 ace7083d6b UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ConsumerPortallink&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:44:26.503&quot; ObjectVal ue=&quot;5c130ae1 e889adc20891 a57fb043968359a6565cefa21 acc7083d6b89bbc6359d8d3b05ae2621 becdf1 b41 d4de0am UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAM S&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ConsumerPortalToken&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20 :44:26.503&quot; ObjectVal ue=' 'https://consumergateway. ipipeIi ne. com/&quot; UpdatedBy=&quot;5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a&quot; LogonlD=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=&quot;STEPHEN&quot; LastName=&quot;ABRAMS&quot; ObjectName=&quot;ConsumerPortalUrl&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-20 20:39:43.127&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;9.0.0.0&quot; UpdatedBy=''5fbb8075-b756-43d7-93e3-cd0626df714a'' LoganID=&quot;4xsdaGRD6641&quot; FirstName=''STEPHEN&quot; LastName=''ABRAM S'' ObjectName=' 'CossCustomAssemblyFrameworkVersion''/&gt;&lt; Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 23:00:27.06&quot; ObjectValue=&quot;20181221230027&quot; UpdatedBy=''1 b9d4a8f-ecd8-42da-963c-b4f712f7cde6&quot; Logan ID=&quot;google_113702915019835686546IPL6641 '' FirstName=&quot;&quot; LastName=&quot;&quot; ObjectName=&quot;cossEntitySaveDate&quot;/&gt;&lt;Data UpdatedDateTime=&quot;2018-12-21 21 :01 :41.957&quot; ObjectValue=''&amp;lt;fseq&amp;gt;&amp;lt;frms&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;GuardianScreens&amp;quot; oo=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;1 &amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-US&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-CA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-CO&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-CT&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-DC&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-FL&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-GA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-lA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-lD&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-lN&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-KS&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-LA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-MA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-M D&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-ME&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-Ml&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-MN&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-MO&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-NC&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-NE&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-NJ&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; Mai nApp_Life-N M&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-NV&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_Life-NY&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-OK&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-OR&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-PA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-Rl&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-TX&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-VA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-VT&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-WA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-Wl&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_Life-WV&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_DI-US&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_DI-CA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_DI-CO&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_D1-CT&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_DI-DC&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot; MainApp_D1-FL&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_DI-GA&amp;quot; v=&amp;quot;0&amp;quot;t&amp;gt;&amp;lt;f n=&amp;quot;MainApp_D1-IA&amp;quot; </Figure>
```

I have tried to get the text for each of the elements in the child tags ("Figure" in this case). However the following code shows that the only data in the Figure tag is an image reference.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from lxml import etree


tree=et.parse("C:\\Users\\haudrxr\\Desktop\\ESLOG.xml")
root=tree.getroot()

for child in root:
     for element in child:
        print(child.tag,"/",element.tag,"/",element.attrib,element.text)
```

For each element I expect to see:
`Figure / ImageData / {'src': 'images/Z4114390 ESLOG_img_NUMBER.jpg'} / RELEVANT TEXT FOR THE CHILD ELEMENT........`

Instead I get: 
`Figure / ImageData / {'src': 'images/Z4114390 ESLOG_img_Number.jpg'} / None`

How could we get that text string after the ImageData tag for each Figure tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant text you want to print is part of the child object (`Figure` tag of your xml) and not of the element object (`ImageData` tag of your xml).

Therefore you have to call element.text to get the text between `Figure` tag
and it's first child and element.tail to for the text close to it's closing tag (have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text)).

```py
for child in root:
    for element in child:
        print(child.tag,"/",element.tag,"/",element.attrib, element.tail)
```